# How often are STUN servers actually used in WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc, stun

Every time I set up WebRTC video call clients, it never works unless I specify a TURN server. No matter how many STUN servers I supply, it always falls back onto TURN. It could be the case that the people I have tested on all coincidentally happened to be behind symmetric NAT. The only time it doesn't fall back to TURN is when I test locally on my own network. Are STUN servers just very infrequently or rarely used? Or are they used more often and my experience just happens to be anomalous.

Answer (score 3):

STUN servers get used very sparingly, during session setup, to help WebRTC endpoints behind NATs discover their public IP addresses. STUN services put a *very* small load on their server machines. They're similar to the "what's my ip?" websites on the internet.

TURN servers, when needed, relay the media data from endpoint to endpoint. All the video, audio, and media streams go up to a TURN server and then back down to a recipient. The TURN server load is higher. TURN service is only needed when endpoints cannot reach each other via direct peer-to-peer connections.

STUN isn't a substitute for TURN.

Comment: I think he asked the wrong question. The question that I believe he wanted to ask - which I have also asked myself in the past - is how often TURN is used as a fallback for unsuccessfully direct connection between peers.